# C++ How to access private member in class inside std::for_each

Tags: c++, class, vector, foreach, private-members

So I have my class:

```
class base
{
public:
  base  (int member) : m_member(member) {};
  ~base () {};

  void func(void)
  {
    std::for_each(something.begin(), something.end(), [](OtherClass& myOtherClass)
    {
        GLfloat* stuff = myOtherClass.GetStuff();
        m_member = 1; //How can I access the private member here?
    });
  };
private:
  int m_member;
}
```

I get this warning:

```
'm_member' requires the compiler to capture 'this' but the current default capture mode does not allow it
```

And this error:

```
'm_member' undeclared identifier
```

**How can I access the private member m_member inside the foreach?**

Comment: You can pass `this` as parameter to the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the brackets before your lambda you can capture the symbols necessary for the function body. In this case you need to capture `this`, because you use its member:

```
[this](OtherClass& myOtherClass)
    {
        GLfloat* stuff = myOtherClass.GetStuff();
        m_member = 1;
    });
```

See also the [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) about lambdas:

> **capture-list** - comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally beginning with a capture-default.
> Capture list can be passed as follows (see below for the detailed
> description):
>
> [a,&b] where a is captured by value and b is captured by reference.
>
> [this] captures the this pointer by value
>
> [&] captures all automatic variables odr-used in the body of the lambda by reference
>
> [=] captures all automatic variables odr-used in the body of the lambda by value
>
> [] captures nothing

Comment: Sure:) I needed to wait 10min to do that;)

Comment: Oh I didn't know this restriction existed!